# Is there a pragma that prevents archiving?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, pragma

I often find myself writing code that should not be there when I archive (using Xcode) the application for production - for debug purposes.

Is there some `#pragma` that prevents archiving, but still allows building and running the project locally?